# Свой виджет, переменная $instance пустая

Tags: php, wordpress

Добрый день, второй день не понимаю в чем проблема, сделал простой виджет по кодексу:

```
function canva_widgets_init() {
    require get_template_directory() . '/inc/widgets.php';
    register_widget('Canva_Features_Widget');

    register_sidebar( array(
        'name'          => esc_html__( 'Sidebar', 'canva' ),
        'id'            => 'sidebar-1',
        'description'   => '',
        'before_widget' => '<aside id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
        'after_widget'  => '</aside>',
        'before_title'  => '<h2 class="widget-title">',
        'after_title'   => '</h2>',
    ) );

    register_sidebar(array(

        'name' => __('Features section', 'canva'),
        'id' => 'sidebar-features',
        'before_widget' => '',
        'after_widget' => '',
        'before_title' => '<h1 class="widget-title">',
        'after_title' => '</h1>',
    ));
}

class Canva_Features_Widget extends WP_Widget {
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct(
            'foo_widget', // Base ID
            __( 'Widget Title', 'text_domain' ), // Name
            array( 'description' => __( 'A Foo Widget', 'text_domain' ), ) // Args
        );
    }

    public function widget($args, $instance) {
        echo $args['before_widget'];
        echo '<div class="ololo">';
        if ( ! empty( $instance['title'] ) ) {
            echo apply_filters( 'widget_title', $instance['title'] );
        }
        echo '</div>';
        echo $args['after_widget'];
    }

    public function form($instance) {
        $title = (!empty($instance['title'])) ? $instance['title'] : __('New title', 'canva');
        ?>
        <p>
            <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'title' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Title:' ); ?></label>
            <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'title' ); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'title' ); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $title ); ?>">
        </p>
    <?php
    }

    public function update($new_instance, $instance) {
        $instance['title'] = strip_tags( $new_instance['title']);
        return $instance;
    }
}
```

В бд все сохраняется, виджет работает в админке, но ничего не выводит на фронтенде, если сделать `var_dump($instance)`, то он пуст...

Вывожу так:

```
the_widget('Canva_Features_Widget');
```

Подскажите, где копать?

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как не соответствующего теме, потому что этот сайт предназначен для общения на русском языке.

Comment: Что ж за день сегодня такой. Уже третий пост такой

Comment: As follows from the name, Russian is the working language of this site. Please either translate your question into Russian or [ask the same question on StackOverflow in English](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). This question may get closed soon, but if you choose to translate, it will surely be reopened, once the translation is done.